# How to create svg maps with the markers and on hover tool tip

Tags: javascript, svg

Am an amateur web developer and am curious to know how to create SVG maps like the one in [this page](http://www.xignite.com/#world-map-markers) with the markers in desired location and on hover tool tip showing the country name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map on the linked page is created using jVectorMap. http://jvectormap.com/

Another approach is to manually mark up an svg. You can add classes, ids, and link tags inline in an svg and target those elements using css and javascript. That's how we did the map on this contact page. http://www.robinsonenclosures.com/contact/